# why my App still visible in task manager after finishing it

Tags: android

I'm calling `finish()` if a certain condition was met. However, even after `finish()` if i hold the home button i can still see my app there. If killing the process is not a desirable option, what should I do?

This is where i'm calling `finish()`:

```
    protected void onStart() {
.............
if(today.equals("..."))
finish();

    };
```

I know that finish will finish the activity but why is it still visible in the task manager? I've finished it.

Comment: `finish()` just kills the Activity, not the whole application. What are you trying to do? Why do you need it to be gone?

Comment: but my app has only one Activity. Main.java only.

Comment: Yeah, but there's a process that contains any activities you have, even if you have only one, and that's the one that is still running.

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330200/how-to-quit-android-application-programmatically) may help

Comment: the thing is that when pressing and holding the home button to open task manager the user can see the app with the progress bar, and it's like not really professional showing the progress bar within the app in the application task manager

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pressing (and holding) HOME button doesn't open task manager. This is some sort of "Recent Apps" section which shows you recently opened apps. Actually it is a bit smarter than that - it can restore last visited activity, but since you have only one activity, this shouldn't be really important for you

So basically even if you can see your app in this list, it doesn't mean it is actually running.

Comment: The only correct and exact answer is the one with less votes (until now at least)! You've got my up vote!

Comment: After looking up different ways to exit an application `onDestroy()` or `finish()`  or `android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
super.onDestroy();` in `onDestroy()`...  They all led to this behavior.  I am glad to see that the activity is not on the stack and just hiding away in a list of recent apps.  

Thank you! +1

Comment: While it is true that the recent's isn't exactly a task manager, this misses the main point made by Srikant, which is that finish() is not by design intended to normally result in process termination.

Answer (score 11):

[finishAndRemoveTask()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.AppTask.html#finishAndRemoveTask()) is the new API that as per the documentation
"Finishes all activities in this task and removes it from the recent tasks list."

```
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21)
{
    finishAndRemoveTask();
}
else
{
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

finish() tells the android system that you are done. It is up to the android system to decide when to actually kill your application. It will keep your application around as long as the OS doesn't require the resources. For the OS, keeping your application in RAM is cheaper than restarting the app. This strategy is true for most modern OS.

Comment: Also as @Pavel Dudka mentioned, long pressing the home button doesn't open the task manager, but simply opens list of recently launched apps (at least on the phones I have seen).

Answer (score 5):

> If killing the process is not a desirable option, what should I do?

Nothing, most likely.

> I know that finish will finish the activity but why is it still visible in the task manager?

First, your process is still running. This is an optimization, so if the user elects to return to your app right away, or something else triggers your app code (e.g., `AlarmManager`), Android does not have to waste CPU and battery forking another process for you right away. Android will terminate your process when it deems this to be appropriate.

Note that depending on what you consider the "task manager" to be, your app may appear there anyway, even if your process is terminated. For example, long-pressing HOME or pressing the RECENTS button brings up "recent tasks", which includes tasks for which the process has been terminated.

> it's like not really professional showing the progress bar within the app in the application task manager

I have no idea why you would think that. That being said, you are welcome to [override `onCreateThumbnail()` in your activities](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateThumbnail%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20android.graphics.Canvas%29) to return something else to use for the thumbnail image.

Answer (score 1):

Processes stay in `S`uspended state :

```
 PID USER       VSZ STAT COMMAND
 --- ----       --- ---- -------
 5846 root         0 SW<  [ksdioirqd/mmc1]
 5853 u0_a76    306m S    {android.youtube} com.google.android.youtube
 5897 root      1852 S    /sbin/sh -
 5922 u0_a79    286m S    {om.me.mygdxgame} com.me.mygdxgame
 5947 u0_a49    278m S    {roid.dspmanager} com.bel.android.dspmanager
 5965 root      1844 R    ps -w
```

Even when all Activities are closed.

There is no harm in keeping stuff loaded in RAM when there's plenty space. Volatile RAM IC's consumes power, empty or full. Suspended processes do not hog CPU. These processes will be terminated when space is required. Until then, they serve to be quickly resumable and make OS faster.

The situations when you'll need to look for running processes are:

1. Poorly managed run away threads. You start a thread which runs a loop, don't know it will ever end, and on top loose all references to it.
2. Badly implemented, and very often, *leaked* Services. Registering service with a system manager/service and forgetting to *unregister*.
3. System processes run via `Runtime.exec()`, and forgetting to call `destroy()` on them.

If you are just dealing with simple Android components and have implemented their life-cycle correctly. You never need worry about internal processes.