# Force close app as in a settings by code

Tags: java, android, forceclose

im lookin a way how to force close app like when using `

> Settings -> application->installed->MyApp ->Force close.

`
It's possible?
im just tested threed  and put there Toast , and it's make toast always while app not force closed. I want when i leave from my app - just Fully close my app. :) please

Comment: lol what ? no i want do it normaly

Comment: use `System.exit(0);` or use `android.os.Process.killProcess( android.os.Process.myPid());`

Comment: @SagarPilkhwal buddy, where i must put this code? can u tell ?

Comment: Put the code at the place where you want to close your app

Comment: if you want the user to click a button and exit you can put the code in its click listiner

Comment: @SagarPilkhwal put ur answer, im assepted it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
final Button mClose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.force_close);
mClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {           
        System.exit(0);
        //or you can use 
        //android.os.Process.killProcess( android.os.Process.myPid());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

It will **destroy** the app.

Alternatively, you can do this -

```
Intent homeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
homeIntent.addCategory( Intent.CATEGORY_HOME );
homeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(homeIntent);
```

This will take you to the home screen and the current processes will be **paused**.

Answer (score -1):

This question was already discussed here : [How to quit android application programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330200/how-to-quit-android-application-programmatically)

You should let the OS decides when the resources should be freed or not. Using all other methods can lead you to not stable state like : not saving data, not calling onStop(), etc... You should be really careful forcing the app to be closed.

You can have some details about closing your application yourself here : [Is quitting an application frowned upon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon)

Comment: But this will just close a activity, not the whole app

Comment: Yes. I edited my post to add some details. The point is : "Should we close the app ourself or letting the OS to decide it ?"