# Closing an app after OK button in a Dialog is clicked

Tags: android, dialog

I have custom Dialog that I wish to have close the app when the user clicks on the OK button. How do I do that?

```
public class PromptDialog extends Dialog {
    TextView removeMsg;
    public PromptDialog(Context context){
        super(context);
        setContentView(R.layout.dlg_prompt);
        removeMsg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.confirmText);
        Button okBut = (Button)findViewById(R.id.confirmBut);
        okBut.setOnClickListener(okButClick);
    }
    View.OnClickListener okButClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
        dismiss();
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Please add the code that show this dialog.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330200/how-to-quit-android-application-programmatically

Comment: You could use `System.exit(0);` or `yourMainActivity.finish();`, However, it's not adviceable that you terminate your app programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

instead of dismiss the dialog, you can get the activity that call this dialog, and finish it.

```
View.OnClickListener okButClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
        getActivity().finish();
        }
    };
```

Comment: yes it bad. but it answer the OP question. what the OP want maybe the confirmation dialog when user press back button on certain activity

Comment: I can't seem to call getActivity() from within my dialog. The method is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have an activity like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements PromptDialog.CommunicationWithActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


PromptDialog promptDialog = new PromptDialog(this/*your context*/, this/*Your communication interface*/);
        promptDialog.show(); // call your dialog and pass interface to it
        }

    public void finishActivity() {
        this.finish();
    }
}
```

And in Dialog class:

```
public class PromptDialog extends Dialog {
    TextView removeMsg;

    private CommunicationWithActivity mCallBack;

    public interface CommunicationWithActivity {
        public void finishActivity();
    }

    public PromptDialog(Context context, CommunicationWithActivity mCallBack){
        super(context);
        this.mCallBack = mCallBack;
        setContentView(R.layout.dlg_prompt);
        removeMsg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.confirmText);
        Button okBut = (Button)findViewById(R.id.confirmBut);
        okBut.setOnClickListener(okButClick);
    }
    View.OnClickListener okButClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mCallBack.finishActivity();
            dismiss();
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: How do I call the PromptDialog then? What would be the CommunicationWithActivity parameter from the caller function?

Comment: Please post your custom layout, so i can run example.

Comment: I don't think I have a custom layout for the dialog. The dialog is already defined in my original post. When I want to call it, I simply instantiate it with a    final PromptDialog promptDialog = new PromptDialog(context);
   promptDialog.show();
 and then a promptDialog.show();

Comment: Post this file dlg_prompt.xml