# Android how to close a running app on back press?

Tags: android, onbackpressed

How to exit from an app on back press of main activity? 
I am using this code, but its finish main activity and show other activities from back stack.

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        finish();
    }
```

Comment: There are many posts on this topic already, i.e. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330200/how-to-quit-android-application-programmatically

Comment: my work is related to session expired. not only back press

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I tried this and its work for me really well,as I am working on app, where once session get expired, user is able to see only few views and remain hidden.

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use

`android:noHistory="true"`
in manifest under activity tag like this

```
    <activity 
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:noHistory="true">
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
@override
public void onBackPressed(){
Intent a = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
a.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
a.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(a);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also try this,

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
       int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
       android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this one :

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        new AlertDialog.Builder(Activityname.this)
        .setTitle("Title")
        .setMessage("Do you really want to exit?")
        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
                ActivityCompat.finishAffinity(Activityname.this);
                finish();   
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        })
        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
        .show();

    }
```

Hope it will solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

[Already asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330200/how-to-quit-android-application-programmatically). most popular answer:

```
getActivity().finish();
System.exit(0);
```

Comment: my java teacher said System.exit(0); would be like jumping out the window instead of using the door.

Answer (score 0):

Hi try adding this code inside onBackPressed:

```
getActivity().finish();
System.exit(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to Exit ?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    moveTaskToBack(true);
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    dialogInterface.cancel();
                }
            });
    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(UserProfile.this, Login.class)
                            .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Answer (score -2):

try
 `public void onBackPressed() {
     finish();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
    }`

use  finish(); after migrating from one activity to another