# How another app exit on android?

Tags: android

I want In `Main app` button click, `B App` exit.

in other words, I want another app exit  on android.

I know my app exit command.

```
moveTaskToBack(true);
finish();
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid())
```

but this source. recently execute app exit source.

perhaps, use package name ? 
please advice for me.

thanks.

@update

add manifest

`uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES"/>`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
  am.killBackgroundProcesses("app exit package name");
  }
}
```

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38842962/i-really-really-want-a-close-button-to-terminate-the-android-application/38843217#38843217

Comment: simply create a broadcast and receive it in the Activity you wanna close

Comment: Or start A Activity by startActivityForResult and onButton click receieved it and finish that Activity. But for this you must have to start your Activity from that particular activity

Answer (score 0):

You can use the killBackgroundProcesses() method of ActivityManager:

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
am.killBackgroundProcesses(packageName);
```

Please, note that your app needs to own the KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES permission. Thus, in the AndroidManifest.xml, you need to include:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />
```

Comment: thanks. but it not work . please check update question .:)