# Get the context of Activity in a Serializable class

Tags: android, android-activity, serialization, android-context

I have a class that implements 'Serializable' but i am unable to get the context of my main activity in it. 
Here is my code for this class:

```
public class Game implements Serializable{
private String name;
private ColorTheme theme;
private int distance = 0;
private int score = 0;
boolean boom = false;
protected Context context;

public Game(MainActivity context){
    this.context = context.getApplicationContext();
}
```

After this i thought i get the context and then what i want is that when the score is greater than 1 then the app should closed.

```
score = (i+1);
if (score >1)
{

}
```

I want to close my game inside this condition but it is not giving me any option to finish the context. Please help me where i am wrong. I think the context is not successfully implemented in this Serializable class. Help needed

Comment: How do you want to close your game? From the **Game** POJO?

Comment: I want to close when the score is greater than 1

Comment: Ok, but WHO is going to do that? The **Game** class?

Comment: Yes, this score condition is in the Game Class that implements Serializable but i am not getting the context of my main activity in this game class

Comment: Ok, I the is such a BAD BAD design! POJOs classes like **Game** should not be responsible for such things! That MUST be done from your Activity class, or better from your Presenter class if you are using MVP design pattern!

Comment: can u plz help me how to do this from my activity class? like first i had to get the score in my main acitivity and then put a condition and then finish

Comment: Just make a Game object in your Activity and every time you increase / decrease the score property just check if your condition is satisfied. If YES - finish the Activity. If you do it in your activity you will not even need to use Context at all.

Comment: You need to redirect user from this activity to another for setting clear top in intent to close all activities and there you have to check by bundle value and close activity so entire app will be closed

Comment: @TodorKostov Ok thankyou so much

Comment: @Vickyexpert i got you too thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FYI**

Closing an application inside the Game class, is not a good approach, it's better to do it inside the Activity itselfs.
A good solution for this could be creating a method inside the Game class like the following:

```
public boolean shouldCloseApplication(){
  return this.score > 1;
}
```

and in the Activity, use the following:

```
if(game.shouldCloseApplication()){
  //close the application as mentioned below
  this.finishAffinity();
}
```

---

Said that, if you wanna close the application, you simply need to call

```
this.finishAffinity();
```

[refer to this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27765687/4700782).

So, instead of passing "`MainActivity`", use directly the "`Context`" passing it with

```
Game game = new Game(MainActivity.this);
```

and receiving with

```
public Game(Context context){
  this.context = context;
}
```

and use it with

```
if(score > 1)
{
  context.finishAffinity();
}
```

---

**Not suggested, but works**

if this doesn't work, use

```
context.getActivity().finish();
System.exit(0);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Ok let me try this one SIr

Comment: As mentioned in the comments bellow the original question - this is a BAD design!

Comment: @TodorKostov what do you mean? which part is a bad design?

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley check the discussion bellow the original question.

Comment: @TodorKostov you mean the System.exit(0)?

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley no, I mean that **Game** should not be responsible for finishing and killing activities / the app etc. Thus, having the Context attribute in the **Game** POJO is a bad design.

Comment: @TodorKostov ok, I think this exactly same as you, but this is not about my answer, if he wants to do it and he is asking about how to do this thing, I simply told him how to solve this problem, because this is what an answer should do. btw I will add the tip about not suggested solution

Comment: @TodorKostov done, I've added a suggested solution for this, but my opinion is still that if he ask for something, he might have his reasons

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley now your FYI edit is way better! Simply giving the OP an answer for his / her problem is not enough. He / She will think that THIS is the right way of solving the problem without even asking himself if there is a better way. And in future when working with other more experienced developers, the OP will have huge problems. And his reasons for approaching this problem in this way are wrong.

Comment: @TodorKostov Never thought at this point of view. Thanks a lot! I will keep it in mind for my future answers

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
public Game(MainActivity context){
this.context = context;
}


score = (i+1);
if (score >1){

PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
                        Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
                        i.addCategory("android.intent.category.HOME");
                        List<ResolveInfo> lst = pm.queryIntentActivities(i, 0);
                        if (lst != null) {
                            for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : lst) {
                                try {
                                    ApplicationInfo ai = pm.getApplicationInfo(
                                                    resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName,0);
                                    if ((ai.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0) {
                                        Intent goHome = new Intent();
                                        goHome.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                        goHome.setClassName(
                                                resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName,
                                                resolveInfo.activityInfo.name);
                                        context.startActivity(goHome);
                                        int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
                                        android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
                                        break;
                                    }
                                } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
                                    logMessage(LOG_TYPE_ERROR, "AppConstant-exitFromApp-kill", e.getMessage());
                                }
                            }
                        }

}
```

Comment: the finish() keyword only closes the current activity, it doesn't exit the application if he has more than one activity open in the stack

Comment: Please, add some explanation to your answer like what exactly the code is doing and why! Also please reconsider your design! This is such a bad approach!