# Android App Exit on Back Button

Tags: android, android-studio

I m trying to exit my application on touching the back button. I ve used the usual code, but it only takes out the app from the screen and when i Click on the square box on the bottom right (also tell me whats it called) i can still see the app running the background i want to remove it totally from the system.
i ve tried all of them finish(); and System.exit(0); they just pass the app to the background from the fore ground. I want to remove it completely from the system.

The following the code i am using.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert).setTitle("Exit")
                .setMessage("Are you sure?")
                .setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("no", null).show();

    }
```

Comment: take a look at the similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330200/how-to-quit-android-application-programmatically

Comment: these are giving the same answers as finish(); or System.exit(0); its not working it just takes my app in the background. Than i ve to manually remove it from the background apps by swiping it right.

Comment: Ya i ve tried all of them  finish(); and System.exit(0); they just pass the app to the background from the fore ground.  I want to remove it compeletly from the system. @VolodymyrKhodonovych

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);` will clear previous activities. Using this, `finish()` call won't be necessary.

And `System.exit(0);` is used in java, not android, so don't use this anymore. Use `finish()` or `getActivity().finish()` in fragment to close current activity.

Update:

If you want to kill the app in order to not run any more in background, you need to do something like this

`ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
 am.killBackgroundProcesses(packageName);`

Where packagename is your app package. And you need to provide permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />`. I think this need to be requested on M. Have a try.

Comment: its not working just taking it from foreground to background.

Comment: Please remove your other flags.

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                            //intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();

Comment: i tried with every other app no app ever totally shuts down unless you just swipe it to right manually. i think there is no total exit fuctionality..

Comment: Anyway.. this is not a good idea what are you trying to do. With pleasure.

Answer (score 2):

if you wanna exit the app from main activity , you can just write :

```
finish();
```

or for exit the app from other activity , you should do like this in  other activity :

```
    //in other activity onBackPressed()     
    Intent intent = new Intent(OtherActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
    startActivity(intent);
```

and write this in onCreate() for MainActivity

```
 if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("EXIT", false)) {
        finish();
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

that's work for me and I'll hope it work for you too.

Comment: Don't use `System.exit(0)`. Just `finish()`. This is Android, not java.

Comment: finish() - finishes the activity where it is called from and you see the previous activity.
System.exit(0) - restarts the app with one fewer activity on the stack. So, if you called ActivityB from ActivityA, and System.exit(0) is called in ActivityB, then the application will be killed and started immediately with only one activity ActivityA

Comment: its not working just taking it from foreground to background.

Comment: thats what exactly is happening everytime..!