# How to exit the application when a button was clicked

Tags: android, button

I want to make a `button` that when clicked the application will close.

I tried all the ways to make it but I couldn't.

I tried to make it like that:

```
public void quit()
{
    System.exit(0);
}
```

And it didn't work. And I also tried to make it like that:

```
public void quit()
{
    finish();
}
```

And it also didn't work.

So please if anyone can help me, answer this question.

Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
   intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
   intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
   startActivity(intent);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the click listener of that `button`, try to call either of:

`super.onStop();`

or

`super.onDestroy();`

Answer (score 0):

`quit()` is a method, You need to call it from somewhere. Where did you call it? If you want to invoke that when a button is clicked here is the way

add a button in your XML

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="exit"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp">
</Button>
```

initialize it in your `onCreate`

```
Button buttonOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
```

write callback to be invoked when button view is clicked

```
buttonOne.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
            //Do stuff here you can call your method quit or
            System.exit(0);  // this should work if you want to use it
    }
});
```

and there are many ways read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330200/how-to-quit-android-application-programmatically)