# Close android app when switching screens?

Tags: java, android, exit

I have my app, and I want it to exit once I switch to something else.
example:
when I'm in my app and press the home button, the app should exit, and disappear from the background running apps window.
how would I do this? maybe in onDestroy?

Comment: This happens for the mobile banking Apps. Isnt it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a duplicate of [How to quit android application programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330200/how-to-quit-android-application-programmatically). You can try use `Activity.onPause` method for your purpose, but check some tricky workflows like switching phone off etc.

Comment: still a problem there: when i start the application, it instantly calls onPause

Answer (score 0):

Finish the App `onPause` then the app will not be run in the background.

```
@Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        isForeground = false;
        finish();
    }
```