# Not able to close app from Dialog in android

Tags: android, background, exit-code

I want to add one functionality in app. I want to close the app while I click on exit button but my button is on Dialog so when I try to use finish() is does not do the same. I just want to close the app.Please help.

// code for the same

```
    if (v.getId() == R.id.imgLogout) {

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
        alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?");
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // session.logoutUser();
                finish();


            }
        });
```

// but finish is not working in Dialog

Comment: Why are u starting an activity? U need to use **finish()** to close app.

Comment: I don't see you using `finish()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to quit android application programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330200/how-to-quit-android-application-programmatically)

Comment: I used finish but not working in Dialog

Comment: Must sure before you calling _finish()_ you'r dismissing dialog by _dismiss()_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly in your dialog class pass the context of the caller activities say MainActivit.class context

Now first close the dialog

//so as to avoid the window leaks as on destroying the activity it's context would also get vanished.

```
 dialog.dismiss();
```

and then

```
((Activity) context).finish();
```

Answer (score 1):

First Close All Paused Activity. Than You Can Close App. You Remember this activity is last.

```
if (v.getId() == R.id.imgLogout) {

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
    alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?");
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new OnClickListener() {

     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {                
           finish();
          // context.finish();  if use in fragment
       }
   });
```

Comment: if use fragment than use context.finish();

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way to close app is:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
```

So in your case try this:

```
 if (v.getId() == R.id.imgLogout) {

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
    alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?");
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // session.logoutUser();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();


        }
    });
```