# Quit Application when press logout button

Tags: android, back

When I press `back button` in my android application or close the app, it terminates and I want my app to be terminated when I press the logout button.
I only want my app to be terminated when I press the logout button, otherwise not, whether I press `back button` or close it by minimizing the app.

What should I do?

For the back button, I used this simple code

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    moveTaskToBack(true);

    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) 
    {
        drawer.closeIrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } 
    else
    {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Should I do something with these lines?
Or should make any web services for this?

Comment: are you changing an activity? Did you add any flags?

Comment: i don't think `android.R.id.home` represents your logout button

Comment: Now I'm totally confused. Please explain in details what do you expect to happen, and what doesn't work. And please add all relevant details to the question itself, do not post them in comments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to quit android application programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330200/how-to-quit-android-application-programmatically)

Comment: I am not using any flags

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
         @Override public void onBackPressed() { 
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
 .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
     .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
     { 
    @Override public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
    MyActivity.super.onBackPressed(); } })
     .setNegativeButton("No", null) 
    .show(); }
```

If you do not want the back button to exit the app at all :

```
@Override public void onBackPressed() { 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [finishAffinity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.html#finishAffinity(android.app.Activity))

I will do your work but requires SDK>16

Now your code of onBackPressed() should be

```
@Override public void onBackPressed() { 
  finishAffinity();
 }
```