# Calling startActiity(newIntent()); after successfully taken a picture

Tags: android, camera, fragment

UPDATE: [How to quit android application programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330200/how-to-quit-android-application-programmatically) is useless as I do need to answer the below question, not how to start an activity or close the activity. I need to know if I can start an activity from a fragment and if not how to pass the value from the fragment to the class and do it from there.

Pretty new to this so I need directions please.
I have a class which calls a camera fragment. I want that after a picture is taken and checked based upon some specific parameters, if and only if they are ok a new class is started and the previous one is closed.

Question:

I do the check for the picture taken inside the fragment. May I do startActivity(newIntent) inside the fragment or I need to pass the result of the check in someway to the class and call from there?
If I can do it in the fragment, how can I do it?
If I need to do it in the class, how can I pass to the class the result of the checks and where I can call startActivity() considering I call the fragment in onStart().

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. I managed to open a new intent from within the fragment with the below code:
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), myclass.class);
                getActivity().startActivity(i);

Thanks.