# /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (abort+160), abort crash in Android 10 devices

Tags: android, android-10.0

I recently changed targedtSdk to 29 and made a release. And started getting this crash called abort. Below is the stack trace that I got from play console. All the crashes are happening only in Android 10 devices. Apart from these, there is no other info.

````
   #00  pc 0000000000082fb4  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (abort+160)
   #00  pc 00000000004b4888  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort(char const*)+2268)
   #00  pc 000000000000c5b4  /system/lib64/libbase.so (android::base::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+608)
   #00  pc 0000000000442f8c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::OatHeader::GetCompilerFilter() const+280)
   #00  pc 000000000044a884  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::OatFile::GetCompilerFilter() const+40)
   #00  pc 0000000000455d38  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::OatFileManager::DumpForSigQuit(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&)+376)
   #00  pc 00000000004c1d78  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::Runtime::DumpForSigQuit(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&)+104)
   #00  pc 00000000004d5ad8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::SignalCatcher::HandleSigQuit()+1356)
   #00  pc 00000000004d4b6c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::SignalCatcher::Run(void*)+252)
   #00  pc 00000000000e205c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+36)
   #00  pc 0000000000084af0  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64)```


Made a staged rollout of 50% and the number of crashes for above is around 800 per day with active installs of 1.5M. So this is a major issue.
````

Comment: ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61321845/qt-app-crashes-at-the-destructor-of-stdthread-on-android-10-devices

Comment: We found that the issue was because of upgrading facebook sdk to the latest version, we reverted to the older version and made a release, the issue didn't occur. Following it up with facebook now. Not sure if this is the reason for others as well.

Comment: @Velu,We've faced the same crashes as you, can you share what facebook sdk did you use and the versions of the sdk?

Comment: @notTdar It is not the same issue. 
Hi Velu, Could you please share with me the Facebook version? also, my app report only on Oppo devices

Comment: implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:facebook:5.7.1.1' - was the one which was causing the crash. And implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:facebook:5.4.1.1' is the reverted version which is working fine.

Comment: Hi @Velu Thanks for your answer. How do you know this aar effect to your app? I asked this question because my app doesn't use this aar. So I think I might same your issue, but difference aar. And checking by each aar is not good solution as it have a lot of aars.

Comment: Hi @seal2002, even we were clueless when this issue happened, and when we backtracked we found that this was the only major change and checked in fb issue report, someone had already raised an issue there. I would suggest to do the same, since this is a native crash not much of information would be available. Identify what was the major change you did in the release and try to revert those change & compare. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @Velu, very appreciate with your guideline, I will take a look on my app. This is helpful. Thank you

Comment: Hi, @seal2002, we are seeing the samke kind of error and we are not using that facebook sdk either. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi @DavidSantiagoTuriño, in my case, I use the com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk so my app has same crash wth Velu. I suggest you check again the dependencies of aar, maybe something related?

Comment: I am still facing this issue and I am not even using com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk anywhere in my Flutter app. Although the version I am using for flutter_facebook_auth plugin is 3.5.7.
I don't get it about 2 months ago everything was working fine and now my App has crashed 30 times for installation above 2.5k users. Can anybody tell me what can I do to figure it out?

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this bug，
from
implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:5.11.0'
to
implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:5.4.1'

But can't find the reason

Comment: Hi @yukun, this is not the same issue from Velu has post, but your answer already help me ;-). So if you make your comment on your question is answer, I will vote for it ;-)

Comment: I have the same crash log.I think it's the same one

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64007059/after-upgrade-to-target-29-there-are-so-many-crashes-on-android-10-apex-com-and

Comment: Hi @yukun, I means you have same crash log as Velu, however, Velu downgrade the com.google.ads.mediation:facebook, in your case, it is com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk. So same crash log, but difference aar to make app crash

Comment: com.google.ads.mediation:facebook dependence on com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk.

Comment: From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64007059, it looks like updating to 6.1.0 should fix this too.

Comment: @yukunqian yep, you are right about it :)

Answer (score 2):

I did not use com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk, and have been trying to fix this for a week now. After much research on the web (and finding nothing of use), I decided to bet it was some sort of incompatibility between some lib and the Andriod version. Took the libs out one by one, and found that, in my case at least, the problem was Sentry. Simply not invoking it during app start solved the issue.

Comment: Do you know why Sentry causes this error? I want to use it, but anytime i get a null ref it crashes

Comment: @MarionPiloo never found out. Moved on without sentry and eventually switched it for another similar lib

Answer (score 1):

As per https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/148240970#comment8 it looks like something to be fixed for Android 11 onwards, without a known fix for Android 10.

Answer (score 1):

[image]Audience Network SDK 6.2.0 seems to solve the problem

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/changelog-android#6_2_0