# After upgrade to target 29,there are so many crashes on android 10 /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::OatFileManager::DumpForSigQuit

Tags: android, facebook-audience-network

After upgrading target sdk version to 29, there are so many crashes on android 10:

```
backtrace:
  #00  pc 0000000000082fb4  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (abort+160)
  #01  pc 00000000004b4888  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort(char const*)+2268)
  #02  pc 000000000000c5b4  /system/lib64/libbase.so (android::base::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+608)
  #03  pc 0000000000442f8c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::OatHeader::GetCompilerFilter() const+280)
  #04  pc 000000000044a884  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::OatFile::GetCompilerFilter() const+40)
  #05  pc 0000000000455d38  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::OatFileManager::DumpForSigQuit(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&)+376)
  #06  pc 00000000004c1d78  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::Runtime::DumpForSigQuit(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&)+104)
  #07  pc 00000000004d5ad8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::SignalCatcher::HandleSigQuit()+1356)
  #08  pc 00000000004d4b6c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::SignalCatcher::Run(void*)+252)
  #09  pc 00000000000e205c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+36)
  #10  pc 0000000000084af0  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64)
```

build.gradle is following

```
implementation 'com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:2.1'
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.4.0"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.3.0"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:18.1.0"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.5.0"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.4"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:19.2.0"
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.2.1'
implementation "com.facebook.android:facebook-login:5.15.3"
implementation "com.facebook.android:facebook-messenger:5.15.3"
implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:5.8.0'
```

Anyone seeing similar issues knows what's going on?

Comment: I fixed this bug， from implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:5.11.0' to implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:5.4.1'

But can't find the reason

Answer (score 3):

Update audience-network-sdk to version 6.1.0 can fixed the bug. Tested with some devices on firmware 10