# Facebook Audience 6.2.0 /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::OatHeader::IsDebuggable() const+124) on Android 11

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-audience-network, android-11

After updating to Facebook Audience 6.2.0 from 5.11.0 on an Android app with target SDK 29 I'm seeing a considerable amount of crash reports on a small percentage of Android 11 devices. According to a user that is having this crash and has reinstalled the app several times to test, the crash occurs a few seconds after startup being able to see a loading screen the first time and then immediately after that first time.

```
  #00  pc 00000000004dcd84  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::OatHeader::IsDebuggable() const+124)
  #00  pc 00000000004dd3f4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::OatFileBase::ShouldUnquickenVDex() const+56)
  #00  pc 00000000004dd594  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::OatFileBase::LoadVdex(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, bool, bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*)+80)
  #00  pc 00000000004e1594  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::OatFile::Open(int, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, bool, bool, art::ArrayRef<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const>, art::MemMap*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*)+468)
  #00  pc 00000000004e7d78  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::OatFileAssistant::OatFileInfo::GetFile()+696)
  #00  pc 00000000004e7038  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::OatFileAssistant::OatFileInfo::Status()+76)
  #00  pc 00000000004e7458  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::OatFileAssistant::OatFileInfo::ReleaseFileForUse()+56)
  #00  pc 00000000004ec944  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::OatFileManager::OpenDexFilesFromOat(char const*, _jobject*, _jobjectArray*, art::OatFile const**, std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > >*)+292)
  #00  pc 00000000004a0718  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::DexFile_openDexFileNative(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jstring*, _jstring*, int, _jobject*, _jobjectArray*)+144)
  #00  pc 0000000000010a88  /apex/com.android.art/javalib/arm64/boot-core-libart.oat (art_jni_trampoline+264)
  #00  pc 000000000001f584  /apex/com.android.art/javalib/arm64/boot-core-libart.oat (dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile+244)
  #00  pc 00000000000215d4  /apex/com.android.art/javalib/arm64/boot-core-libart.oat (dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements+1348)
  #00  pc 0000000000020b78  /apex/com.android.art/javalib/arm64/boot-core-libart.oat (dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>+664)
  #00  pc 000000000001d934  /apex/com.android.art/javalib/arm64/boot-core-libart.oat (dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>+228)
  #00  pc 0000000000057f90  /apex/com.android.art/javalib/arm64/boot-core-libart.oat (dalvik.system.DexClassLoader.<init>+80)
  #00  pc 0000000000133564  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+548)
  #00  pc 00000000001a8a78  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+200)
  #00  pc 000000000031830c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+376)
  #00  pc 000000000030e638  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+996)
  #00  pc 000000000067d794  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeDirect+576)
  #00  pc 000000000012d914  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_direct+20)
  #00  pc 00000000001cdc00  /data/app/~~USEx1p9tx0-5YVxYZoz1fQ==/com.mycompany.mygame-OdPieLgz_xrP3A7H8t3zyw==/oat/arm64/base.vdex (com.facebook.ads.internal.dynamicloading.DynamicLoaderFactory.makeLegacyAdsSdkClassLoader+160)
  #00  pc 000000000067e314  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+1224)
  #00  pc 000000000012d994  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_static+20)
  #00  pc 00000000001cdd48  /data/app/~~USEx1p9tx0-5YVxYZoz1fQ==/com.mycompany.mygame-OdPieLgz_xrP3A7H8t3zyw==/oat/arm64/base.vdex (com.facebook.ads.internal.dynamicloading.DynamicLoaderFactory.makeAdsSdkClassLoader+8)
  #00  pc 000000000067e314  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+1224)
  #00  pc 000000000012d994  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_static+20)
  #00  pc 00000000001cd96e  /data/app/~~USEx1p9tx0-5YVxYZoz1fQ==/com.mycompany.mygame-OdPieLgz_xrP3A7H8t3zyw==/oat/arm64/base.vdex (com.facebook.ads.internal.dynamicloading.DynamicLoaderFactory.doMakeLoader+70)
  #00  pc 000000000067e314  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+1224)
  #00  pc 000000000012d994  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_static+20)
  #00  pc 00000000001cd90c  /data/app/~~USEx1p9tx0-5YVxYZoz1fQ==/com.mycompany.mygame-OdPieLgz_xrP3A7H8t3zyw==/oat/arm64/base.vdex (com.facebook.ads.internal.dynamicloading.DynamicLoaderFactory.access$000)
  #00  pc 000000000067e314  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+1224)
  #00  pc 000000000012d994  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_static+20)
  #00  pc 00000000001cd6fa  /data/app/~~USEx1p9tx0-5YVxYZoz1fQ==/com.mycompany.mygame-OdPieLgz_xrP3A7H8t3zyw==/oat/arm64/base.vdex (com.facebook.ads.internal.dynamicloading.DynamicLoaderFactory$a.run+34)
  #00  pc 0000000000305c34  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.16249794272548105830)+268)
  #00  pc 0000000000669e20  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+780)
  #00  pc 000000000013cff8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+88)
  #00  pc 000000000015ab08  /apex/com.android.art/javalib/arm64/boot.oat (java.lang.Thread.run+72)
  #00  pc 0000000000133564  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+548)
  #00  pc 00000000001a8a78  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+200)
  #00  pc 0000000000553890  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JValue art::InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValues<art::ArtMethod*>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, art::ArtMethod*, jvalue const*)+460)
  #00  pc 00000000005a2c2c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::CreateCallback(void*)+1308)
  #00  pc 00000000000af888  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+64)
  #00  pc 000000000004fe08  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64)
```

This is different from the /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (abort+160) issue ([/apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (abort+160), abort crash in Android 10 devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63047553/apex-com-android-runtime-lib64-bionic-libc-so-abort160-abort-crash-in-andro)) which still rarely occurs on 6.2.0.

Comment: I'm having the same issue and I'm in contact with FB support now, could you maybe PM me?

Comment: I received the following info from FB tech support "Upon consultation of this matter, it would be a great help if you could provide more information from other developers, so that we can reproduce the issue." so if anyone has additional info or can even reproduce the issue, please post here.

Comment: Found logs of this issue with FAN 6.2.0 & 6.1.0 but not with 5.11.0.

Comment: I reported these error logs in Galaxy S20, S20+(Android 11). Is this a fixable bug?

Comment: Clearing app data seems to fix the issue (while reinstalling doesn't), thus I'm assuming some problem with fb shared_prefs which is probably backed up by Android when reinstalling. Is anyone having this issue with jetify OFF? I wonder if jetifying the audience_network.dex is causing a problem somehow.

Comment: There's a related issue on fb-samples Audience Github project (https://github.com/fbsamples/audience-network/issues/132) where there's a link to a test build that may fix it.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [change log](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/changelog-android#6_2_1), version 6.2.1 (published on 03Feb2021) of the Android Facebook Audience Network SDK fixes this bug.

Comment: It didn't completely fix the issue. Seems to be a bug in AdMob. You can find some details here: https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk/c/tyXU1DW0wNc

Comment: Also as per comment from https://github.com/fbsamples/audience-network/issues/132 people still get this crash after removing the audience network sdk completely

Comment: I confirm that upgrading from FAN v6.2.0 to v6.2.1 and v6.3.0 did not fix the crash in my app.

Answer (score 0):

I also meet this crash, but not found how to solve it！

Comment: I'm in contact with FB support, can you share with me (PM or here) any details regarding targetSdk, ad type, kotlin/java, when does the crash occur?

Comment: In my case, it's targetSdkVersion 29, native banner, java. Can't tell you at what stage it occurs, only getting it from the dev console.

Answer (score 0):

Feedback from FB tech support: "It looks like this issue was flagged to us previously, and our team has been working to resolve it. It should be fixed when SDK 6.3.0 becomes available."
Unfortunately, no timeline was given for version 6.3.0.