# art::OatHeader::IsDebuggable() const Crash, Android 11, Google Ads SDK 19.7.0

Tags: java, android, crash, admob, android-11

I get this crash on many Android 11 Devices. Target SKD is 29 with build tools 29.0.2.

Anybody else have this problem? What can we do instead of waiting for a new sdk release. I lost a few thousand users because of this crash.

Facebook had a similar problem but fix it with 6.2.1 see this thread: [Facebook Audience 6.2.0 /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::OatHeader::IsDebuggable() const+124) on Android 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64698538/facebook-audience-6-2-0-apex-com-android-art-lib64-libart-so-artoatheaderi)

```
#00  pc 00000000004be3ec  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::OatHeader::IsDebuggable() const+64)
  #00  pc 00000000004bea98  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::OatFileBase::ShouldUnquickenVDex() const+56)
  #00  pc 00000000004bec38  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::OatFileBase::LoadVdex(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, bool, bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*)+80)
  #00  pc 00000000004c30ec  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::OatFile::Open(int, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, bool, bool, art::ArrayRef<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const>, art::MemMap*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*)+472)
  #00  pc 00000000004c9bc8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::OatFileAssistant::OatFileInfo::GetFile()+696)
  #00  pc 00000000004c8dc4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::OatFileAssistant::OatFileInfo::Status()+76)
  #00  pc 00000000004c92b0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::OatFileAssistant::OatFileInfo::ReleaseFileForUse()+56)
  #00  pc 00000000004ce798  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::OatFileManager::OpenDexFilesFromOat(char const*, _jobject*, _jobjectArray*, art::OatFile const**, std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > >*)+292)
  #00  pc 0000000000485ae0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::DexFile_openDexFileNative(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jstring*, _jstring*, int, _jobject*, _jobjectArray*)+144)
  #00  pc 0000000000010a88  /apex/com.android.art/javalib/arm64/boot-core-libart.oat (art_jni_trampoline+264)
  #00  pc 000000000001f744  /apex/com.android.art/javalib/arm64/boot-core-libart.oat (dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile+244)
  #00  pc 0000000000021560  /apex/com.android.art/javalib/arm64/boot-core-libart.oat (dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements+784)
  #00  pc 0000000000020d38  /apex/com.android.art/javalib/arm64/boot-core-libart.oat (dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>+664)
  #00  pc 000000000001d934  /apex/com.android.art/javalib/arm64/boot-core-libart.oat (dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>+228)
  #00  pc 0000000000058630  /apex/com.android.art/javalib/arm64/boot-core-libart.oat (dalvik.system.DexClassLoader.<init>+80)
  #00  pc 0000000000134564  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+548)
  #00  pc 0000000000198e94  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+204)
  #00  pc 000000000030c218  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+376)
  #00  pc 0000000000307330  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+884)
  #00  pc 000000000063d560  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeDirect+592)
  #00  pc 000000000012e914  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_direct+20)
  #00  pc 00000000001764a6  /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000018/dl-AdsFdrDynamite.integ_204890103100000.apk (qb.c+118)
  #00  pc 000000000063d79c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeDirect+1164)
  #00  pc 000000000012e914  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_direct+20)
  #00  pc 00000000001765f8  /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000018/dl-AdsFdrDynamite.integ_204890103100000.apk (qb.a+8)
  #00  pc 000000000063b274  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+1440)
  #00  pc 000000000012e814  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20)
  #00  pc 0000000000094d8a  /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000018/dl-AdsFdrDynamite.integ_204890103100000.apk (ec.c+26)
  #00  pc 000000000063b274  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+1440)
  #00  pc 000000000012e814  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20)
  #00  pc 00000000000949fe  /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000018/dl-AdsFdrDynamite.integ_204890103100000.apk (ec.a+70)
  #00  pc 00000000002fed0c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.5884005180817902658)+268)
  #00  pc 00000000003069d4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+200)
  #00  pc 0000000000307314  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+856)
  #00  pc 000000000063ddc0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+548)
  #00  pc 000000000012e994  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_static+20)
  #00  pc 00000000000be4fe  /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000018/dl-AdsFdrDynamite.integ_204890103100000.apk (com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.i.run+162)
  #00  pc 00000000002fed0c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.5884005180817902658)+268)
  #00  pc 00000000006299e8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+796)
  #00  pc 000000000013dff8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+88)
  #00  pc 00000000002a2ae8  /apex/com.android.art/javalib/arm64/boot.oat (java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker+984)
  #00  pc 000000000029fce0  /apex/com.android.art/javalib/arm64/boot.oat (java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run+64)
  #00  pc 000000000015cdf8  /apex/com.android.art/javalib/arm64/boot.oat (java.lang.Thread.run+72)
  #00  pc 0000000000134564  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+548)
  #00  pc 0000000000198e94  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+204)
  #00  pc 00000000005320fc  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+104)
  #00  pc 00000000005332fc  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JValue art::InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValues<art::ArtMethod*>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, art::ArtMethod*, jvalue const*)+440)
  #00  pc 000000000058081c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::CreateCallback(void*)+1272)
  #00  pc 00000000000b6374  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+64)
  #00  pc 0000000000050fa4  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64)
```

Comment: I update to 19.8.0 but the crash is still there

Comment: Here is a Google Groups Thread about this Issue: https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk/c/tyXU1DW0wNc?pli=1

Comment: And cleaning play services data & cache seems to fix the problem for affected users

Comment: Do you still observe the issue? I check AdMob release notes constantly but don't see any related changes. I'm currently on play-services-ads:20.0.0, and the crash is still present for a large group of my users.

Comment: Hi Orange, I also still have this issue. So far I understand we have to wait for the device manufacturers to distribute the patch. It looks like samsung has already distributed the patch. At least I don't have any more Samsung android 11 crashes.

Answer (score 5):

It's nothing we can do for now except removing google ads for android 11 devices or suggest our users to clear play services cache & data.

Answer from google:

> This is a bug at the Android platform level. Details:
>
> Bug - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/182081085#comment5 Source
> patch -
> https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/art/+/1642063/
>
> Unfortunately, as described in the bug link above, this doesn't help
> devices that are upgrading to Android 11, and clearing cache is the
> workaround.

Comment: Thanks for the links. It is really annoying. Why can't this be fixed? As many users do not know how to clear the cache, we usually disable ads on android 11 for these users. A massive loss in revenue. this there really no workaround??