# Abort crashes from "/apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so" on Android 11

Tags: android

I know there is [a similar question for Android 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63047553/apex-com-android-runtime-lib64-bionic-libc-so-abort160-abort-crash-in-andro). I see occasional abort crashes on Android 11. The backtrackes of these crashes are not 100% identical, but very similar.
Could anyone shed some light on the possible causes?

Here are two backtraces for example:

From a Samsung device:

```
backtrace:
  #00  pc 000000000004f064  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (abort+164)
  #00  pc 000000000053b008  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort(char const*)+2340)
  #00  pc 000000000001394c  /system/lib64/libbase.so (android::base::SetAborter(std::__1::function<void (char const*)>&&)::$_3::__invoke(char const*)+76)
  #00  pc 0000000000006d10  /system/lib64/liblog.so (__android_log_assert+336)
  #00  pc 0000000000041b24  /system/lib64/libmedia_jni.so (android::JMediaCodec::configure(android::sp<android::AMessage> const&, android::sp<android::IGraphicBufferProducer> const&, android::sp<android::ICrypto> const&, android::sp<android::hardware::cas::native::V1_0::IDescrambler> const&, int)+488)
  #00  pc 0000000000045668  /system/lib64/libmedia_jni.so (android_media_MediaCodec_native_configure(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jobjectArray*, _jobjectArray*, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobject*, int)+588)
  #00  pc 0000000000253200  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (art_jni_trampoline+272)
  #00  pc 000000000067a3d0  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.media.MediaCodec.configure+1472)
  #00  pc 000000000067b034  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.media.MediaCodec.configure+68)
  #00  pc 0000000000134564  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+548)
  #00  pc 0000000000198e94  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+204)
  #00  pc 000000000030c218  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+376)
  #00  pc 0000000000307330  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+884)
  #00  pc 0000000000641874  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtualQuick+708)
  #00  pc 0000000000132594  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual_quick+20)
```

From a Xiaomi device:

```
backtrace:
  #00  pc 0000000000089acc  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (abort+164)
  #00  pc 000000000055ebf4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort(char const*)+2308)
  #00  pc 0000000000013978  /system/lib64/libbase.so (android::base::SetAborter(std::__1::function<void (char const*)>&&)::$_3::__invoke(char const*)+76)
  #00  pc 0000000000006e18  /system/lib64/liblog.so (__android_log_assert+336)
  #00  pc 0000000000040068  /system/lib64/libmedia_jni.so (android::JMediaCodec::configure(android::sp<android::AMessage> const&, android::sp<android::IGraphicBufferProducer> const&, android::sp<android::ICrypto> const&, android::sp<android::hardware::cas::native::V1_0::IDescrambler> const&, int)+488)
  #00  pc 0000000000043a80  /system/lib64/libmedia_jni.so (android_media_MediaCodec_native_configure(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jobjectArray*, _jobjectArray*, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobject*, int)+588)
  #00  pc 000000000013ced4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_generic_jni_trampoline+148)
  #00  pc 0000000000133564  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+548)
  #00  pc 00000000001a8a78  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+200)
  #00  pc 0000000000319b78  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+376)
  #00  pc 0000000000310f64  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<true, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+696)
  #00  pc 0000000000683e10  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeDirectRange+436)
  #00  pc 000000000012dc14  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_direct_range+20)
  #00  pc 00000000004f5410  [anon:dalvik-classes2.dex (android.media.MediaCodec.configure+328)
  #00  pc 0000000000683fb0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeDirectRange+852)
  #00  pc 000000000012dc14  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_direct_range+20)
  #00  pc 00000000004f58cc  [anon:dalvik-classes2.dex (android.media.MediaCodec.configure+12)
  #00  pc 0000000000685060  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtualQuick+1344)
  #00  pc 0000000000131594  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual_quick+20)
```

Answer (score 0):

same problem. only xiaomi, android 11.

```
#00 pc 00037700 /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (abort+171) [armeabi-v7a::edc23b5a08cb25fcac190e6392a4d537]
#01 pc 0022e130 __kmp_abort_process + 48 [armeabi-v7a]
```