# How to kill application onBackpress?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, onbackpressed, onkeydown

Does anyone know how to kill application after onBackpress on Android ? I using this code to close my application.

```
  @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
        if (Integer.parseInt(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK) < 5
                && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
                && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
            Log.d("CDA", "onKeyDown Called");
            onBackPressed();

        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    public void onBackPressed() {

            Log.d("CDA", "onBackPressed Called");
            Intent setIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            setIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            setIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            startActivity(setIntent);
      return;

    }
```

My case , after I close the application using backpress the application not kill the application. I mean after I close the app and I open it again the application start with the last (acitivity) where I close the application (using backpress)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27765687/7339411

Comment: @Curio it's work when I'm using this.finishAffinity(); after startActivity(setIntent). Thanks

Comment: If you managed to solve your problem, do not edit your question to 'fix' the problem in the question (invalidating the question) nor add things like "[SOLVED]" to the title. Instead **accept** the answer that helped you solve the problem, or - if there is no such answer - post your own answer. Accepting an answer is what marks a question as solved. I have rolled back your question to its initial state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `this.finishAffinity();` after `startActivity(setIntent);` in your case, as suggested in this answer here [stackoverflow.com/a/27765687/7339411](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27765687/7339411)

Note that since API 21 you can use `finishAndRemoveTask();` as well.

Answer (score -1):

Use ***finish()*** inside *onBackPressed()*.

Comment: This answer should have been [expanded like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16480930/1291879). As it is, it should have of been a comment.