# How to exit from android app after start a new activity?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm developing 2 android application, first with Xamarin.Forms (A) and the other one with native android (B).

I have a button in A app which open B app.
**Code**:

PackageManager pm = Application.Context.PackageManager;

```
            if (IsAppInstalled(packageName))
            {
                Intent intent = pm.GetLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);

                if (intent != null)
                {
                    intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
                    Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);
                }
            }
```

In B app i have to collect some datas then pass datas to A app.

```
Intent browserIntent = App.AppContext.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("xxx");
            browserIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            browserIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
            browserIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

            browserIntent.putExtra("xx","");
            browserIntent.putExtra("xz","2");        

            startActivity(browserIntent);
```

**How can i exit from B app after go back to A app?**

Comment: `...exit from B app after go back to A app...` You have, once you start the "A" activity from app "B", app "B" is now in the background and app "A" is the foreground app. If you are trying to programmatically remove app "B" from the task manager/list, you can not.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You pointed out that remove app from task list is not possible.

Answer (score -1):

If I understood correctly, you'd like to close the activity, this can be done by using

```
finish();
```

command.

Comment: I tried finish() after startActivity, but its not working for me. B app stay in background.

Comment: I also tried that and not working. Exit and killprocess also not working. :(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330200/how-to-quit-android-application-programmatically